# MySQL select rows based on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` query based on two other table data.
`_sites_` array has 5 objects, `_cats_` array has 12 objects for now. So, in order to get `news` based on these objects, I have to make `12 * 5` sql query repeatedly. (For each category & site)

How can I reduce query count?

```
getSites(function (_sites_) {
    getCategories(function (_cats_) {

        var array = []

        async.each(_sites_, function (site, next) {
            async.each(_cats_, function (cat, next2) {

                var sql = "SELECT * "+
                          "FROM news "+
                          "WHERE category = ? AND site = ? "+
                          "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30"

                db.query(sql, [cat.data, site.data], function (result) {
                    array = array.concat(temp)
                    next2()
                })

            }, function () {
                next()
            })

        }, function () {
            // finished
            console.log(array)
        })

    })
})  


function getCats (pass) { //get used categories
    db.query("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cat_name in (SELECT news_url.rss_cat FROM news_url)"+
             "ORDER by cat_pos ASC", [], function (result) {
                var array = []

                if(result) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                        array.push({type: 1, data:result[j].cat_name})
                    };
                }

                pass(array)
    })
}


function getSites (pass) {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM news_url", [], function (result) {

        var array = []

        if(result) {
            for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                array.push({type: 0, data:result[j].rss_site})
            };
        }

        pass(array)
    })
}
```

---

**cats** table: (categories)

```
|id|cat_name|cat_pos|
|1 |Fun     | 1     |
|1 |Bomm    | 2     |
```

**news_url** table: (rss site names and urls)

```
|id|rss_site|rss_url   |rss_cat
|1 |Cnn     |http://...|Fun 
|2 |Fox     |http://...|Bomm
|3 |Cnn     |http://...|Bomm
|4 |Routers |http://...|Fun
```

**news** table:

```
|id|news_site | news_cat | news_content
|1 | Cnn      | Bomm     | Some random news content from Cnn
|2 | Cnn      | Fun      | Some random news content from Cnn
|3 | Fox      | Fun      | Some random news content from Fox
```

Expected result is a separate N-row limit for each combination of category and site. If it's possible using a few queries.

Comment: Is there a way you can join the tables to do it in one query? It sounds possible, but without seeing some sample data and expected results (or at least your table structures) I'm not sure.

Comment: I updated my question based on your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: So what do you mean by each combination of category and site? Just a list of (cnn, fun), (cnn, bomm), (fox, fun), (fox, bonn), all the way down the list?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing x * y queries for now to get these rows but there must be light and fast way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to query separately for each category for each site, then why are you doing that?  If you just omit the `WHERE` clause from the query you are using now, then in one go it will give you all the news for all categories and sites, subject to the 30-row `LIMIT` you have placed.

It will be trickier if you want a separate 30-row limit for each combination of category and site, as your current approach provides, but I'm inclined to suspect that the `LIMIT` isn't doing quite what you want it to do now, or at least that it would not be doing so if you had more data.

**Edited to add:**

If, as you indicate in comments, you really do want a 30-row limit for each combination of category and site then, for mysql, I see only two alternatives:

- form one giant query by connecting all the individual queries you now perform via the `UNION ALL` operator.  Submit only that query.  This is likely your best bet, but you could also
- use a simple query with no `WHERE` clause, as I first suggested, and apply the row limits on the node.js side.  This approach might be facilitated by ordering additionally by site and category.  Although this results in a simpler query, it may involve many rows being transferred and then discarded.

Comment: As you said, I want a separate 30-row limit for each combination of category and site. That is what I want to achieve. So LIMIT is important.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll go with second one.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a Cartesian Product. You get this when you select from two different tables without defining a relationship between them. So, for a simple example:

```
SELECT rss_site, cat_name
FROM categories, news_url;
```

Will return every possible (rss_site, cat_name) combination. I would note, however, that since you have a few repeated rss_site values (cnn in your sample data) you may want to add `DISTINCT` in your select clause to only get distinct pairs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rss_site, cat_name
FROM categories, news_url;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4c3/2) example.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get news from news table using this cartesian, N-row limit for each combination? My biggest problem is this. But your help is definitely helped.

Comment: @Lazy there's a few questions here tagged [tag:greatest-n-per-group] is that what you're looking for? I'll try to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually I'll just be brutally honest I might not be able to edit right away, but I will try to come back later with a sample query when I can. Let me know if you end up solving it though!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should probably be something like this:

`var sql = "SELECT * "+
"FROM news "+
"WHERE category in (?) AND site in (?) "+
"ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30"`

given that you have two arrays and not just two values.